# Qlikview macro to automatically Fit zoom to window

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense

How can i create a macro to automatically Fit zoom to window.

I cant see an options to do this via a trigger.

Preferably i would like this macro to be triggered when the screen resolution changes, if not possible i would like it to be set when you change sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl + m to open the macro editor

```
Sub FZTW    
    ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.FitZoomToWindow  
End Sub
```

Set when sheet activate trigger macro `FZTW`

Answer (score 1):

for anybody who searched for **Fit Zoom to Window** and end up here

1. enable plugin in server and check show download link
2. client now download the plugin& go to detail and view it with this around 96mb plugin.
3. inside plugin top toolbar go to Menu->Zoom->**Fit Zoom to Window**

[image]
[image]
[image]